# Load SIMULINK Model from MATLAB GUI, domain error

Tags: matlab, dns, simulink

i need to open an existing simulink model from my Matlab GUI. I am not into Simulink at all and i just have to make it work somehow. To open the model i use the command

```
open_system('filepath_to_model')
```

Now an error occurs:

```
Warning: Physical modeling domain definition file psatdomain.m not found. You will not be able simulate this model. Please close
your model, then add the domain definition file to the MATLAB path and re-open your model.
```

What does this error mean? i added *psatdomain.m* to the directory of the model but the error remains the same.

% PSATDOMAIN defines the domain for the PSAT-Simulink library

I would be glad for your help so that i can open an existing Simulink model and run it from my Matlab GUI.

Thank you very much!!

Best regards, John

Comment: Do you have any custom blocks in your Simulink model that need this `psatdomain.m` file? If the absolute/relative path to it is hard-coded somewhere in those block definitions, you might be better adding the original path to the file to the MATLAB path rather than copying it to the model directory. You might also want to check your [model callbacks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/model-callbacks.html) for any calls to that MATLAB file.

Comment: I guess the first step to debug this would be to try and open the Simulink model from MATLAB and see if you have the same error. If not, it's something to do with the GUI and most likely is a path/directory issue.